# Android Keyboard, custom popuplayout in Nougat

Tags: layout, keyboard, android-7.0-nougat

i developed a keyboard that works without issue on MM and lower. By the way on Nougat i have a layout issue, check this images to understand better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGQIo.jpg.

The 1st image is on Nougat ( the popup isn't showed completely) the 2nd is like appeared on MM ( all the lines are showed correctly ).

I used this xml to customize the popup:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/aosp_pressed">
    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@android:id/keyboardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/key_background"
        android:keyTextColor="#fff"
        android:background="@color/aosp_background"
        android:keyTextSize="25sp"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@android:id/closeButton"
        android:background="@color/aosp_pressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see the issue is caused by the position of the popup that isn't showed outside the keyboard. How can i solve this issue?
Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: Do you fix the issue? I'm having the same problem. :s

Answer (score 0):

What is your @layout/preview like?

My theory is that in between Android 6 and 7, the time when wrap_content chooses it's size changed.

Before when using

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/xxxxx"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout> //PARTIAL CODE!
```

there were no problems in 6.0. The text view would expand to fit the text and then be centered.

However, in 7, the text gets displayed completely vertically suggesting that the initial LinearLayout was getting set to a width of 0 and not adjusting.

Try playing with the height in your @layout/preview, or in your closeButton. Set them to manual heights and see if things change accordingly!